# pecl install redis: When you enable igbinary, do you need to enable lzf and zstd compression? (phpredis)

Tags: redis

When I fire the command

```
sudo pecl install redis
```

I get asked to enable:

```
enable igbinary serializer support? [no] :
enable lzf compression support? [no] :
enable zstd compression support? [no] :
```

In a blog post it says: Using igbinary serializer reduces stored data size about 3x times.

When you enable igbinary, do you need to enable lzf and zstd compression?

Answer (score -1):

If you want **accept** all, you can use:

```bash
yes|pecl install -f redis
```

If you **DO NOT want accept** any, you can use:

```bash
yes 'no'|pecl install -f redis
```